# By passing octal literal deprecation in Scala 2.13

Tags: scala

I am using [this tool](https://github.com/strubell/jflex-scala) that generates a scala file (instead of the Java file that jFlex generates).

But the problem is its generates string literals with octals like this:

```
val ZZ_CMAP_PACKED:String = 
    "\11\0\1\2\1\1\2\0\1\2\22\0\1\2\7\0\4\3\1\0"+
    "\1\3\1\0\1\3\12\4\44\0\1\3\uffa1\0";
```

But these octal literals are deprecated and [cannot be used in scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0r1dkoaJSnS4HH7egmuugA). I am wondering is there a `scalac` flag that can accept octal literals. I am trying to fix the problem in the simplest way possible without forking that repo.

```
/* The following code was generated by JFlex 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT (+scala) on 7/24/14 3:35 PM */

/**
 * This class is a scanner generated by 
 * <a href="http://www.jflex.de/">JFlex</a> 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT (+scala)
 * on 7/24/14 3:35 PM from the specification file
 * <tt>Calc.lex</tt>
 */
class CalcScanner(private var zzReader : java.io.Reader) extends Iterator[CalcTokens.YYToken] {
  def this(in : java.io.InputStream) = this(new java.io.InputStreamReader(in));

  /** This character denotes the end of file */
  val YYEOF : Int = -1;

  /** initial size of the lookahead buffer */
   private val ZZ_BUFFERSIZE:Int =  16384;

  /** lexical states */
  val YYINITIAL:Int = 0;

  /**
   * ZZ_LEXSTATE[l] is the state in the DFA for the lexical state l
   * ZZ_LEXSTATE[l+1] is the state in the DFA for the lexical state l
   *                  at the beginning of a line
   * l is of the form l = 2*k, k a non negative integer
   */
   private val ZZ_LEXSTATE:Array[Int] = Array(
     0, 0
  );

  /** 
   * Translates characters to character classes
   */
   private val ZZ_CMAP_PACKED:String = 
    "\11\0\1\2\1\1\2\0\1\2\22\0\1\2\7\0\4\3\1\0"+
    "\1\3\1\0\1\3\12\4\44\0\1\3\uffa1\0";

  /** 
   * Translates characters to character classes
   */
   private val ZZ_CMAP:Array[Char] = zzUnpackCMap(ZZ_CMAP_PACKED);

  /** 
   * Translates DFA states to action switch labels.
   */

   private val ZZ_ACTION_PACKED_0:String = 
    "\1\0\1\1\1\2\1\3\1\4\1\5";

  private def zzUnpackAction() : Array[Int] =  {
    val result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](6);
    var offset:Int = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackAction(ZZ_ACTION_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private def zzUnpackAction(packed:String,offset:Int,result:Array[Int]) : Int =  {
    var i:Int = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    var j:Int = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    val l:Int = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      var count:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      var value:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      do { result(j) = value; j+=1; count -= 1; } while (count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }
   private val ZZ_ACTION:Array[Int] = zzUnpackAction();


  /** 
   * Translates a state to a row index in the transition table
   */

   private val ZZ_ROWMAP_PACKED_0:String = 
    "\0\0\0\5\0\12\0\17\0\12\0\24";

  private def zzUnpackRowMap() : Array[Int] =  {
    val result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](6);
    var offset:Int = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackRowMap(ZZ_ROWMAP_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private def zzUnpackRowMap(packed:String,offset:Int,result:Array[Int]) : Int =  {
    var i:Int = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    var j:Int = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    val l:Int = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      val high:Int = packed.charAt(i) << 16; i+= 1;
      result(j) = high | packed.charAt(i); i+= 1; j += 1;
    }
    return j;
  }
   private val ZZ_ROWMAP:Array[Int] = zzUnpackRowMap();

  /** 
   * The transition table of the DFA
   */

   private val ZZ_TRANS_PACKED_0:String = 
    "\1\2\1\3\1\4\1\5\1\6\1\2\13\0\1\4"+
    "\6\0\1\6";

  private def zzUnpackTrans() : Array[Int] =  {
    val result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](25);
    var offset:Int = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackTrans(ZZ_TRANS_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private def zzUnpackTrans(packed:String,offset:Int,result:Array[Int]) : Int =  {
    var i:Int = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    var j:Int = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    val l:Int = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      var count:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      var value:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      value-= 1;
      do { result(j) = value; j+=1; count -= 1; } while (count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }
   private val ZZ_TRANS:Array[Int] = zzUnpackTrans();


  /* error codes */
  private val ZZ_UNKNOWN_ERROR : Int = 0;
  private val ZZ_NO_MATCH : Int = 1;
  private val ZZ_PUSHBACK_2BIG : Int = 2;

  /* error messages for the codes above */
  private val ZZ_ERROR_MSG: Array[String] = Array(
    "Unkown internal scanner error",
    "Error: could not match input",
    "Error: pushback value was too large"
  );

  /**
   * ZZ_ATTRIBUTE[aState] contains the attributes of state <code>aState</code>
   */

   private val ZZ_ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_0:String = 
    "\1\0\1\1\1\11\1\1\1\11\1\1";

  private def zzUnpackAttribute() : Array[Int] =  {
    val result:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](6);
    var offset:Int = 0;
    offset = zzUnpackAttribute(ZZ_ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_0, offset, result);
    return result;
  }

  private def zzUnpackAttribute(packed:String,offset:Int,result:Array[Int]) : Int =  {
    var i:Int = 0;       /* index in packed string  */
    var j:Int = offset;  /* index in unpacked array */
    val l:Int = packed.length();
    while (i < l) {
      var count:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      var value:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      do { result(j) = value; j+=1; count -= 1; } while (count > 0);
    }
    return j;
  }
   private val ZZ_ATTRIBUTE:Array[Int] = zzUnpackAttribute();


  /** the current state of the DFA */
  private var zzState : Int = 0;

  /** the current lexical state */
  private var zzLexicalState : Int = YYINITIAL;

  /** this buffer contains the current text to be matched and is
      the source of the yytext() string */
  private var zzBuffer : Array[Char] = new Array(ZZ_BUFFERSIZE);

  /** the textposition at the last accepting state */
  private var zzMarkedPos : Int = 0;

  /** the current text position in the buffer */
  private var zzCurrentPos : Int = 0;

  /** startRead marks the beginning of the yytext() string in the buffer */
  private var zzStartRead : Int = 0;

  /** endRead marks the last character in the buffer, that has been read
      from input */
  private var zzEndRead : Int = 0;

  /** number of newlines encountered up to the start of the matched text */
  private var yyline : Int = 0;

  /** the number of characters up to the start of the matched text */
  private var yychar : Int = 0;

  /**
   * the number of characters from the last newline up to the start of the 
   * matched text
   */
  private var yycolumn : Int = 0;

  /** 
   * zzAtBOL == true <=> the scanner is currently at the beginning of a line
   */
  private var zzAtBOL : Boolean = true;

  /** zzAtEOF == true <=> the scanner is at the EOF */
  private var zzAtEOF : Boolean = false;

  /* user code: */
  // These features are added to the Scanner class
  var lookahead : CalcTokens.YYToken = null;
   
  override def hasNext() : Boolean = { 
    if (lookahead == null) lookahead = yylex();
    lookahead match {
      case x:CalcTokens.YYEOF => false;
      case x:CalcTokens.YYToken => true;
    }
  };
  
  override def next() : CalcTokens.YYToken = {
    if (lookahead == null) lookahead = yylex();
    var result : CalcTokens.YYToken = lookahead;
    lookahead = null;
    result
  };
  
  def getLineNumber() : Int = yyline+1;



  /**
   * Creates a new scanner
   * There is also a java.io.InputStream version of this constructor.
   *
   * @param   in  the java.io.Reader to read input from.
   */

  /** 
   * Unpacks the compressed character translation table.
   *
   * @param packed   the packed character translation table
   * @return         the unpacked character translation table
   */
  private def zzUnpackCMap(packed:String) : Array[Char] = {
    val map:Array[Char] = new Array[Char](0x10000);
    var i:Int = 0;  /* index in packed string  */
    var j:Int = 0;  /* index in unpacked array */
    while (i < 34) {
      var count:Int = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      var value:Char = packed.charAt(i); i+= 1;
      do { map(j) = value; j+=1; count-=1; } while (count > 0);
    }
    return map;
  }


  /**
   * Refills the input buffer.
   *
   * @return      <code>false</code>, iff there was new input.
   */
  private def zzRefill() : Boolean = {

    /* first: make room (if you can) */
    if (zzStartRead > 0) {
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, zzStartRead,
                       zzBuffer, 0,
                       zzEndRead-zzStartRead);

      /* translate stored positions */
      zzEndRead-= zzStartRead;
      zzCurrentPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzMarkedPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzStartRead = 0;
    }

    /* is the buffer big enough? */
    if (zzCurrentPos >= zzBuffer.length) {
      /* if not: blow it up */
      val newBuffer : Array[Char] = new Array(zzCurrentPos*2);
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, zzBuffer.length);
      zzBuffer = newBuffer;
    }

    /* finally: fill the buffer with new input */
    val numRead : Int = zzReader.read(zzBuffer, zzEndRead,
                                      zzBuffer.length-zzEndRead);

    if (numRead > 0) {
      zzEndRead+= numRead;
      return false;
    }
    // unlikely but not impossible: read 0 characters, but not at end of stream    
    if (numRead == 0) {
      val c : Int = zzReader.read();
      if (c == -1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        zzBuffer(zzEndRead) = c toChar;
        zzEndRead += 1
        return false;
      }     
    }

    // numRead < 0
    return true;
  }

    
  /**
   * Closes the input stream.
   */
  def yyclose() : Unit = {
    zzAtEOF = true;            /* indicate end of file */
    zzEndRead = zzStartRead;  /* invalidate buffer    */

    if (zzReader != null)
      zzReader.close();
  }


  /**
   * Resets the scanner to read from a new input stream.
   * Does not close the old reader.
   *
   * All internal variables are reset, the old input stream 
   * <b>cannot</b> be reused (internal buffer is discarded and lost).
   * Lexical state is set to <tt>ZZ_INITIAL</tt>.
   *
   * @param reader   the new input stream 
   */
  def yyreset(reader : java.io.Reader) : Unit = {
    zzReader = reader;
    zzAtBOL  = true;
    zzAtEOF  = false;
    zzEndRead = 0; zzStartRead = 0;
    zzCurrentPos = 0; zzMarkedPos = 0;
    yyline = 0; yychar = 0; yycolumn = 0;
    zzLexicalState = YYINITIAL;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the current lexical state.
   */
  def yystate() : Int = {
    zzLexicalState;
  }


  /**
   * Enters a new lexical state
   *
   * @param newState the new lexical state
   */
  def yybegin(newState : Int) : Unit = {
    zzLexicalState = newState;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the text matched by the current regular expression.
   */
  def yytext() : String = {
    new String( zzBuffer, zzStartRead, zzMarkedPos-zzStartRead );
  }


  /**
   * Returns the character at position <tt>pos</tt> from the 
   * matched text. 
   * 
   * It is equivalent to yytext().charAt(pos), but faster
   *
   * @param pos the position of the character to fetch. 
   *            A value from 0 to yylength()-1.
   *
   * @return the character at position pos
   */
  def yycharat(pos : Int) : Char = {
    zzBuffer(zzStartRead+pos);
  }


  /**
   * Returns the length of the matched text region.
   */
  def yylength() : Int = {
    zzMarkedPos-zzStartRead;
  }


  /**
   * Reports an error that occured while scanning.
   *
   * In a wellformed scanner (no or only correct usage of 
   * yypushback(int) and a match-all fallback rule) this method 
   * will only be called with things that "Can't Possibly Happen".
   * If this method is called, something is seriously wrong
   * (e.g. a JFlex bug producing a faulty scanner etc.).
   *
   * Usual syntax/scanner level error handling should be done
   * in error fallback rules.
   *
   * @param   errorCode  the code of the errormessage to display
   */
  private def zzScanError(errorCode:Int) : Unit =  {
    var message : String = null;
    try {
      message = ZZ_ERROR_MSG(errorCode);
    } catch {
      case e:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException =>
        message = ZZ_ERROR_MSG(ZZ_UNKNOWN_ERROR);
    }

    throw new Error(message);
  } 


  /**
   * Pushes the specified amount of characters back into the input stream.
   *
   * They will be read again by then next call of the scanning method
   *
   * @param number  the number of characters to be read again.
   *                This number must not be greater than yylength()!
   */
  def yypushback(number:Int) : Unit =  {
    if ( number > yylength() )
      zzScanError(ZZ_PUSHBACK_2BIG);

    zzMarkedPos -= number;
  }

  /** Nested class to simulate multi-level break */
  private case class ZZbreak(name:String) extends Throwable;

  /**
   * Resumes scanning until the next regular expression is matched,
   * the end of input is encountered or an I/O-Error occurs.
   *
   * @return      the next token
   * @exception   java.io.IOException  if any I/O-Error occurs
   */
  def yylex() : CalcTokens.YYToken = 
 {
    var zzInput : Int = 0;
    var zzAction : Int = 0;

    // cached fields:
    var zzCurrentPosL : Int = 0;
    var zzMarkedPosL : Int = 0;
    var zzEndReadL : Int = zzEndRead;
    var zzBufferL : Array[Char] = zzBuffer;
    var zzCMapL : Array[Char] = ZZ_CMAP;

    val zzTransL:Array[Int] = ZZ_TRANS;
    val zzRowMapL:Array[Int] = ZZ_ROWMAP;
    val zzAttrL:Array[Int] = ZZ_ATTRIBUTE;

    while (true) {
      zzMarkedPosL = zzMarkedPos;

      var zzR:Boolean = false;
      zzCurrentPosL = zzStartRead
      while (zzCurrentPosL < zzMarkedPosL) {
        (zzBufferL(zzCurrentPosL)) match {
        case '\u000B'
        |'\u000C'
        |'\u0085'
        |'\u2028'
        |'\u2029' => {
          yyline+=1;
          zzR = false;
          }
        case '\r' => {
          yyline+=1;
          zzR = true;
          }
        case '\n' => {
          if (zzR)
            zzR = false;
          else {
            yyline+=1;
          }
          }
        case _ => {
          zzR = false;
          }
        }
        zzCurrentPosL += 1;
      }

      if (zzR) {
        // peek one character ahead if it is \n (if we have counted one line too much)
        var zzPeek:Boolean = false;
        if (zzMarkedPosL < zzEndReadL)
          zzPeek = zzBufferL(zzMarkedPosL) == '\n';
        else if (zzAtEOF)
          zzPeek = false;
        else {
          val eof:Boolean = zzRefill();
          zzEndReadL = zzEndRead;
          zzMarkedPosL = zzMarkedPos;
          zzBufferL = zzBuffer;
          if (eof) 
            zzPeek = false;
          else 
            zzPeek = zzBufferL(zzMarkedPosL) == '\n';
        }
        if (zzPeek) yyline-= 1;
      }
      zzAction = -1;

      { val p : Int = zzMarkedPosL;
        zzCurrentPosL = p; zzCurrentPos = p; zzStartRead = p;
      }
  
      zzState = ZZ_LEXSTATE(zzLexicalState);

      // set up zzAction for empty match case:
      var zzAttributes:Int = zzAttrL(zzState);
      if ( (zzAttributes & 1) == 1 ) {
        zzAction = zzState;
      }


      /* zzForAction: */ try {
        while (true) {
    
          if (zzCurrentPosL < zzEndReadL) {
            zzInput = zzBufferL(zzCurrentPosL);
            zzCurrentPosL += 1;
          } else if (zzAtEOF) {
            zzInput = YYEOF;
            throw ZZbreak("zzForAction");
          }
          else {
            // store back cached positions
            zzCurrentPos  = zzCurrentPosL;
            zzMarkedPos   = zzMarkedPosL;
            val eof:Boolean = zzRefill();
            // get translated positions and possibly new buffer
            zzCurrentPosL  = zzCurrentPos;
            zzMarkedPosL   = zzMarkedPos;
            zzBufferL      = zzBuffer;
            zzEndReadL     = zzEndRead;
            if (eof) {
              zzInput = YYEOF;
              throw ZZbreak("zzForAction");
            }
            else {
              zzInput = zzBufferL(zzCurrentPosL);
              zzCurrentPosL += 1;
            }
          }
          val zzNext:Int = zzTransL(zzRowMapL(zzState) + zzCMapL(zzInput));
          if (zzNext == -1) throw ZZbreak("zzForAction");
          zzState = zzNext;

          zzAttributes = zzAttrL(zzState);
          if ( (zzAttributes & 1) == 1 ) {
            zzAction = zzState;
            zzMarkedPosL = zzCurrentPosL;
            if ( (zzAttributes & 8) == 8 ) throw ZZbreak("zzForAction");
          }

        }
      } catch { case ZZbreak("zzForAction") => () }

      // store back cached position
      zzMarkedPos = zzMarkedPosL;

      (if ( zzAction < 0 ) zzAction; else ZZ_ACTION(zzAction)) match  {
        case 3 => {
          { 
          }
          }
        case 6 => {}
        case 1 => {
          { println("Ignored characters: " + yytext);
          }
          }
        case 7 => {}
        case 5 => {
          { return CalcTokens.NUM(Integer.parseInt(yytext));
          }
          }
        case 8 => {}
        case 2 => {
          { return CalcTokens.YYCHAR('\n');
          }
          }
        case 9 => {}
        case 4 => {
          { return CalcTokens.YYCHAR(yytext.charAt(0));
          }
          }
        case 10 => {}
        case _ =>
          if (zzInput == YYEOF && zzStartRead == zzCurrentPos) {
            zzAtEOF = true;
              {
                return CalcTokens.YYEOF();
              }
          } else {
            zzScanError(ZZ_NO_MATCH);
          }
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("NOT REACHED");
  }


}
```

Comment: Generally, when library X depends on deprecated feature Y, the answer is to update library X, not to reimplement feature Y. That project's latest commit is in 2015, which is the stone age when it comes to software libraries. You can either fork the repo and fix it yourself, or forget about the clearly-abandoned library and do your work another way. But trying to pull Scala *back* in time isn't going to solve any problems.

Comment: Is that even a valid octal string? `"\11\0\1\2\1\1\2\0\1\2\22\0\1\2\7\0\4\3\1\0\1\3\1\0\1\3\12\4\44\0\1\3\uffa1\0"`; what is "\uffa1"??